# JS - file onload() doesn't work with android browser

Tags: javascript, html, upload, touch

I have a application similar to the example http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/K3A9r/
But if I use this concept for file upload on a iPad/android it does not work. The image is not loaded into the browser wether with onload() nor with onloadend()

html:

```
<input type="file" name="myFileSelect" />
```

js:

```
 // Bind to the change event of our file input
$("input[name='myFileSelect']").on("change", function(){

// Get a reference to the fileList
var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];

// If no files were selected, or no FileReader support, return
if ( !files.length || !window.FileReader ) return;

// Only proceed if the selected file is an image
if ( /^image/.test( files[0].type ) ) {

    // Create a new instance of the FileReader
    var reader = new FileReader();

    // Read the local file as a DataURL
    reader.readAsDataURL( files[0] );

    // When loaded, set image data as background of page
    reader.onloadend = function(){

        $("html").css("background-image", "url(" + this.result + ")");

    }

   }

});
```

Comment: Any update on this?  A year later, and I'm dealing with the exact same problem on my Samsung Galaxy 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File.API works from android browser 3.0+
or user firefox on the android device

http://mobilehtml5.org/

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the onloadend event is well supported in android or ios.  IE 10 does not support this event on FileReader as well, I think.  Perhaps you should rely on the onload event instead.